# Codeigniter - SQL Server 2008 : How to get parameter output in Store Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I’ve a procedure in SQL Server 2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testing
    @parm varchar(10),
    @parmOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @parmOUT = 'parm 1 ' + @parm
END
```

and i have a query to access this procedure in Codeigniter frameword.
i use sqlsrv_driver database.

```
$param1 = 'test';
$param2 = '1';
$this->db->query("dbo.testing ?,  ?", array($param1, $param2));
```

i’ve execute the procedure, but i can’t retrieve 2nd parameter value ($param2).

Anyone have idea to get this 2nd parameter value??

thanks b4

Answer (score 0):

In your Stored Procedure ,you are passing one input parameter and the specifying one output parameter . So the SP should be modified like the one below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.testing
@parm varchar(10),
@parmOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  'parm 1 ' + @parm
END
```

Now in order to execute the above SP you need to pass just one input parameter

```
 declare @out varchar(30)
 exec testing 'test', @parmOUT=@out OUTPUT
```

You will just retrieve the result as

```
 param1test
```

There is no second parameter which you can retrieve from your SP .The only value which you will get is the one which you have specified in your select query .

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's no result value after query.

Comment: Can you be please more specific as to what result you need to get when you get execute the stored procedure

Comment: thanks 4 your response...
i want to get the output parameter into variable $param2 in php,not @out in query.

Comment: @MochZawaruddinAbdullah : I don't know how to do that in PHP but the exec statement which i have written retrieves the output parameter only .In order to store the output value you need to declare a variable with output keyword and then assign the value to it

Comment: ok ... thank you for your attention .. I have solve it ...
I am using SQL Server PDO

Comment: It @MochZawaruddinAbdullah it would be helpful for community of you can answer how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'DECLARE @RETURNV VARCHAR(20)
EXEC dbo.testing ?, @parmOUT= @RETURNV OUTPUT
SELECT @RETURNV AS RETURNV';
$param = array(
  "This is first param"
);
$temp = $this->db->query($sql, $param);
$result = $temp->result_array();
echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: Whenever you answer, please try put some explanation around that so that everyone gets exactly what you wanted to convey in you answer.